# Unable to import tkinter.messagebox as "tk.messagebox"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-import, tkmessagebox

In my code, I have imported the main tkinter modules using the line:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

I can then reference tkinter modules for example as `tk.Button()`.

I would like to also import the `tkinter.messagebox` module, which I am aware must be imported specifically.

However, I'd like to be able to reference it like `tk.messagebox()` to stay consistent with the rest of my code. As far as I can tell, there is no way to achieve this.

What I have tried include:

```py
import tkinter.messagebox as tk.messagebox # Invalid syntax
```

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tk.messagebox # No module named 'tk'
```

```py
from tkinter import messagebox as tk.messagebox # Invalid syntax
```

Is there any way to import `tkinter.messagebox` to be referenced as `tk.messagebox()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done as below:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

tk.messagebox.showinfo("INFO", "Hello World")
# or tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(...)
```

Note that you cannot use the module as a function, like `tk.messagebox()`.

Comment: For brevity's sake, I tend to to `import tkinter.messagebox as tkm`

Comment: @JRiggles, that would not be correctly answering the question. They want to stay consistent by sacrificing brevity.

Comment: @SanguineL I'm aware, I'm merely expressing my preference on the off-chance someone finds it helpful. I did not mean to suggest that acw1668 was incorrect in any way (they usually aren't!)

Comment: @JRiggles, gotcha. I, too, prefer brevity.